# How manage a VIEW with Doctrine 2?

Tags: mapping, doctrine-orm, sql-view, temp-tables, nativequery

I would like mapping a sql-view with **Doctrine2**.

This view is a **TempTable** containing some statistics that would show without rewriting the sql that generates the view

I try to map like a table, but updating schema drop the view and create a table

I try also with NativeSQL...

```
public function getMessages(\Project\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\User $user) {
    $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('MessageCenter', 'v');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('v', 'user_id', 'user_id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('v', 'tot', 'tot');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('v', 'read', 'read');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('v', 'to_read', 'to_read');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('v', 'stored', 'stored');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('v', 'spam', 'spam');

    $q = "SELECT * FROM message_stats_view WHERE user_id = ?";
    $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($q, $rsm);
    $query->setParameter(1, $user->getId());
    echo $query->getSQL();
    var_dump($query->execute());
    exit;
}
```

I create the entity MessageCenter with getter and setter, but my output is:

```
SELECT * FROM message_stats_view WHERE user_id = ?
array
  empty
```

Comment: btw: you are overwriting $rsm before using it..

Answer (score 1):

(Answered by the OP in aq question edit. Transcribed to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I SOLVED!!!!

```
public function getCentroMessaggi(\Project\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\User $user) {
    $connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    $q = "SELECT * FROM message_stats_view WHERE user_id = :id";
    $stmt = $connection->executeQuery($q, array('id' => $user->getId()));
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

> This return an array. PERFECT!